# Eclipse "Java was started but returned exit code=13

Tags: java, c++, eclipse

[image]

I got the following problem when i installed the latest version of java(8), everything was ok before
please help!

Comment: do java -version on command prompt. I think its to do with 32 bit/64 bit jvm.. And what's your OS? Also remove C++ tag as it has nothing to do with c++.

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse and almost certainly a 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by editing the Environment variable PATH, just remove the first line before the semi-colon 
its something like C:/ProgramData/Oracle... and add your 64bit java Variable

Answer (score 2):

your latest version of java is 32 bit or 64 bit? It should be the same as your JDK, ECLIPSE and OS are. ALL should be same 32 bit or 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Change path of your Eclipse put your "Eclipse" folder C:\Program Files (x86) or C:\Program Files

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Mine got resolved by pointing the Java version to its 64 bit version. Like many pointed out here your Eclipse, Java, and the OS should of the same bit architecture. You can start Eclipse either using command prompt (in Windows) by giving command like **C:\eclipse>eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe"** or by double clicking on the exe file. For the second option, you need to change the eclipse.ini file by giving the vm path using the -vm option so that it won't take the default Java version for your computer. I placed mine just before the -vmargs option. See my setup below:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 0):

I got mine to work by installing the 32 bit java along side the 64 bit java version.  Should work the same if you need the reverse.